# Android running tweetdeck notifications when not running

Tags: notifications, twitter, tweetdeck

I downloaded Tweetdeck for my new Galaxy S 3 and when it is not running in the task list or in the `app manager | running apps` it still notifies me of new tweets. How can I see this task running and how to disable it? I don't see it in services or in the Tweetdeck options to disable background services.

Comment: Did you check the running services (a separate item in *setup -> applications* on most Android systems)? The app might have registered a background service, which has no "front end" (visible part), and thus is not listed with the "running apps".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tweetdeck, each column has separate notification and update settings.    Tap the menu key, then Column Settings.     Switch notify off, and set your desired update interval, or move the slider all the way to the right to select "Manual".

Comment: Thanks. Guess when that is checked it just Runs in the background unless all are disabled.